# Efficiency of guava Table vs multiple hash maps

Tags: java, guava, performance

I ran across some code that was doing something like this:

```
Map<String,String> fullNameById = buildMap1(dataSource1);
Map<String,String> nameById = buildMap2(dataSource2);
Map<String,String> nameByFullName = new HashMap<String,String>();
Map<String,String> idByName = new HashMap<String,String>();

Set<String> ids = fullNameById.keySet();
for (String nextId : ids) {
  String name = nameById.get(nextId);
  String fullName = fullNameById.get(nextId);
  nameByFullName.put(fullName, name);
  idByName.put(name, nextId);
}
```

I had to stare at it for several minutes to figure out what was going on. All of that amounts to a join operation on id's and an inversion of one of the original maps. Since Id, FullName and Name are always 1:1:1 it seemed to me that there should be some way to simplify this. I also discovered that the first two maps are never used again, and I find that the above code is a bit hard to read. So I'm considering replacing it with something like this that (to me) reads much cleaner

```
Table<String, String, String> relations = HashBasedTable.create();

addRelationships1(dataSource1, relations);
addRelationships2(dataSource2, relations);

Map<String,String> idByName = relations.column("hasId");
Map<String,String> nameByFullName = relations.column("hasName");
relations = null; // not used hereafter
```

In addRelationships1 I do

```
relations.put(id, "hasFullName", fullname);
```

And in addRelationships2 where my query yields values for `id` and `name` I do

```
relations.put(relations.remove(id,"hasFullName"), "hasName", name);
relations.put(name, "hasId", id);
```

So my questions are these:

1. Is there a lurking inefficiency in what I have done either via processor or memory, or GC load? I don't think so, but I'm not that familiar with the efficiency of Table. I am aware that the Table object won't be GC'd after `relations = null`, I just want to communicate that it's not used again in the rather lengthy section of code that follows.
2. Have I gained any efficiency? I keep convincing and unconvincing myself that I have and have not.
3. Do you find this more readable? Or is this only easy for me to read because I wrote it? I'm a tad worried on that front due to the fact `Table` is not well known. On the other hand, the top level now pretty clearly says, "gather data from two sources and make these two maps from it." I also like the fact that it doesn't leave  you wondering if/where the other two maps are being used (or not).
4. Do you have an even better, cleaner, faster, simpler way to do it than either of the above?

Please Lets not have the optimize early/late discussion here. I'm well aware of that pitfall. If it improves readability without hurting performance I am satisfied. Performance gain would be a nice bonus.

**Note:** my variable and method names have been sanitized here to keep the business area from distracting from the discussion, I definitely won't name them addRelationships1 or datasource1! Similarly, the final code will of course use constants not raw strings.

Comment: I replaced a buttload of `HashMaps`, just like yours, with `Table` too and was very happy with the results. Recall that `HashBasedTable` is not the only type you can use.

Comment: Having a two-row `Table` instead of maintaining two maps and using them directly is strictly less efficient, but only by a constant.

Comment: @Wasserman the point of comparison, is A) generating 2 maps and iterating them to produce 2 more Maps, vs B) building 1 table and then getting 2 maps from the table. The final output in both cases is the same two maps: `nameByFullName` and `idByName`. Only Those are used thereafter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So I did some mini benchmarking myself and came up with the conclusion that there is little difference in the two methods in terms of execution time. I kept the total size of the data being processed constant by trading runs for data-set size. I did 4 runs and chose the lowest time for each implementation from among all 4 runs. Re-reassuringly both implementations were always fastest on the same run. My code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5110608). Here are my results:

```
Case                      Maps (ms)   Table (ms)    Table vs Maps
100000 runs of size 10    2931        3035          104%
10000 runs of size 100    2989        3033          101%
1000 runs of size 1000    3129        3160          101%
100 runs of size 10000    4126        4429          107%
10 runs of size 100000    5081        5866          115%
1 run  of size 1000000    5489        5160          94%
```

So using Table seems to be slightly slower for small data sets. Something interesting happens around 100,000 and then by 1 million the table is actually faster. My data will hang out in the 100 to 1000 range, so at least in execution time the performance should be nearly identical.

As for readability, my opinion is that if someone is trying to figure out what is happening near by and reads the code it will be significantly easier to see the intent. If they have to actually debug this bit of code it may be a bit harder since `Table` is less common, and requires some sophistication to understand.

Another thing I am unsure of is whether or not it's more efficient to create the hash maps, or to just query the table directly in the case where all keys of the map will subsequently be iterated. However that's a different question :)

And the comedic ending is that in fact as I analyzed the code further (hundreds of lines), I found that the only significant use of nameByFullname.get() outside of logging (of questionable value) was to pass the result of the to idByName.get(). So in the end I'll actually be building an idByFullName map and an idByName map instead with no need for any joining, and dropping the whole table thing anyway. But it made for an interesting SO question I guess.

Comment: I had come to the same conclusion about the tradeoffs between Table and a lot of maps. Glad to get some affirmation. +1 though just for the ending.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you wrote is not a fair benchmark. Have you confirmed that the implementation methods that you used in those main methods have the same execution time? I mean the methods you used in both main methods `table` and `map` have different methods that may affect the overall execution time of their calling methods.

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr, but I'm afraid that you'd need to make a bigger step away from the original design. Simulating DB tables might be a nice exercise, but for me your code isn't really readable.

1. *Is there a lurking inefficiency in what I have done...* No idea.
2. *Have I gained any efficiency?* I'm afraid you need to measure it first. Removing some indirections surely helps, but using a more complicated data structure might offset it. And performance in general is simply too complicated.
3. *Do you find this more readable?* I'm afraid not.
4. *Do you have an even better, cleaner, faster, simpler way to do it than either of the above?* I hope so....

Where I get lost in such code is the use of strings for everything - it's just too easy to pass a wrong string as an argument. So I'd suggest to aggregate them into an object and provide maps for accessing the objects via any part of them. Something as trivial as this should do:

```
class IdNameAndFullName {
    String id, name, fullName;
}

class IdNameAndFullNameMaps {
    Map<String, IdNameAndFullName> byId;
    Map<String, IdNameAndFullName> byName;
    Map<String, IdNameAndFullName> byFullName;
}
```

You could obviously replace the class `IdNameAndFullNameMaps` by a `Table`. However, besides using a nice pre-existing data structure I see no advantages therein. The disadvantages are:

- loss of efficiency
- loss of readability (I wouldn't use `Table` here for the very same reason `Tuple` [should be avoided](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard))
- use of String keys (your "hasId" and "hasName").

Comment: I have thought about doing something like this, (it was in fact my first thought) but I don't like classes that are meaningless data bags. I'm not sure why you claim your way is more efficient. The map keys are iterated for building an external data representation, containing all the data, so the additional property access to get the desired value might or might or might not be optimized away by the compiler... And of course I will abstract the strings to constants. (I meant to say that in the question).

Comment: Your link to the idea graveyard is useful though. It is worth noting however that Table as such is not in the idea graveyard.

Comment: @Gus: But this "meaningless data bag" represents a row in a (possible non-existent) table linking all three unique identifiers together. As classes are in Java the only way how to aggregate things, I'd use them. Moreover, this class is trivial and self-describing, unlike the table. And you're right, the indirection from `IdNameAndFullName` to the desired component might cost some time. Using string constants doesn't help you against using a wrong constant. If I were into it, I'd try an enum.

Comment: Well I did upvote you for your help... But the core question (title, and things I put first in the list of questions) were about efficiency, so I can't really give you the check mark, but I do appreciate your help and perspective.